# Migrating from MySQL RDS to Aurora RDS with CNAME record

Tags: migration, aws, aurora

I understand migrating to Aurora is simply a matter of creating read replica from MySQL source and then promoting when caught up and stopping writes on MySQL RDS previous master.

I use Route 53 DNS that has a CNAME record. My plan is to just change the DNS to Aurora cluster but not sure if that is instant? Is there a way to stop the old MySQL RDS instance so it can’t be written to? (It as a Multi-AZ and there is no stop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know you can not replicate Aurora (slave ) from EC2 (master), please correct me if I am wrong. Due to the super grant lack required to do the "Change Master". I would recommend to use DMS (databawse migration server) for that task.

migration steps:

1. set route53 TTL to 1 min
2. set read_only in current master, to make sure no more reads go into the master.
3. wait for all transactions go into the new master.
4. Stop DMS replication
5. change CNAME
   ...

Pay special atention if your application uses sticky connections, if so you can stop the old master completely to make sure all traffic goes into the new one.

Comment: I am moving from RDS Mysql to Amazon Aurora RDS. So I it are saying route 53 ttk 1 minute is all I need?

Comment: Yes , i would do that. so connections will fail only per one min max.